# Converting Librosa features for a lot of songs into a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader, librosa

I'm having an issue with Librosa -- Python music analysis tool. What I'm trying to do is convert audio into mfcc features. The code I have below works perfectly if I don't add restrictions on the audio such as duration and offset.

```
def WebsiteFeatureExtraction(filename):
   data, sample = librosa.load(filename, sr=11025, duration=30, offset=45)
   df = librosa.feature.mfcc(y = data, sr = sample, n_mfcc=10)
   return df
for i in range(0, 30):
  song_name = allsongs[i][46:-5] # allsongs are my songs, I'm choosing the first 30
  dic.update({song_name:WebsiteFeatureExtraction(allsongs[i])})
```

The issue with the code happens on the following line:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic, orient = 'index')
```

It works fine when I don't add the duration and offset on line 2. However, as soon as I add it, I get the error:

```
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input
```

Any help will be great. THanks.

Comment: What's the full traceback?

Comment: And what does `dic` look like when duration and offset are included?